# Ternary Operator in Button causes '...' expected TS(1005) error

Tags: reactjs

I am using a ternary operator in button and facing '...' expected, TS(1005) error. The syntax in question is exactly as provided in the reactjs website. (example:1)

```
(Example: 1)
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'currently' : 'not'}</b> logged in.
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Code is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function LoginSignupModal() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false)
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true)

    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [errorPassword, setErrorPassword] = useState(false)

    function handleRegister() {
        console.log("name", name)
    }
    function handlePasswordConfirmation(data) {
        if (data.target.value != password) {
            console.log("didn't match")
            setErrorPassword(true)
        } else {
            console.log("matched")
            setErrorPassword(false)
        }
    }


    return (
        <>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow} style={{ marginLeft: '5px' }}>
                Signup
        </Button>

            <Modal
                show={show}
                onHide={handleClose}
                backdrop="static"
                keyboard={false}
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Registration Form</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId="signupName">
                            <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control value={name} onChange={(data) => setName(data.target.value)} placeholder="John Doe" />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control value={email} onChange={(data) => setEmail(data.target.value)} type="email" placeholder="xyz@email.com" />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control value={password} onChange={(data) => setPassword(data.target.value)} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPasswordConfirmation">
                            <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" onChange={(data) => handlePasswordConfirmation(data)} placeholder="Re-enter Password" />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <-- **ERROR IN THE FOLLOWING LINE** -->
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" {(errorPassword) ? "disabled" : "active"}>Register</Button>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose} style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>Close</Button>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    By signing up, you agree to our privacy policy and terms and conditions.
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
```

**Here I am trying to add disabled/active on a button depending on errorPassword state. but it's giving me an error.**

Error generating code part:

```
<Button variant="primary" type="submit" {(errorPassword) ? "disabled" : "active"}>Register</Button>
```

Comment: `{(errorPassword) ? "disabled" : "active"}` it should be passed as a prop. like `isActive={(errorPassword) ? "disabled" : "active"}`. Now you can use `props.isActive` to enable/disable the button. Rather pass a boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` and `active` are [separate boolean props](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#active-state), those variants should work:

```
// Recommended
<Button disabled={errorPassword} active={!errorPassword}>
  Register
</Button>

// Unreadable
<Button {...{ [errorPassword ? "disabled" : "active"]: true }}>
  Register
</Button>

// Same as above just a bit more readable
const errorPasswordProps = { [errorPassword ? "disabled" : "active"]: true };
<Button {...errorPasswordProps}>Register</Button>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how material set its ternity in its source-code

```
 <Button {...(errorPassword ? { disabled: true } : { active: true })}>
      Register
 </Button>
```

but the better way to express this would be to define `hasError` property in Button itself and pass `hasError={errorPassword}`